# Exception Handling for UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, exception

I have a question abeout Exception Handling in Spring Security.

I have defined a `CustomUserDetailsService` which sometimes (when the value in SM_USER header is false) should throw an exception.

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {   

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String smHeaderValue)   throws UsernameNotFoundException {                

    ... throw new UsernameNotFoundException("wrong value of the sm Header");        
    ...
}
```

I would like a Http status code 403 (AccessDenied) to be thrown in this case but Spring Security always shows 500. And the standard (for my software) exception representation cannot be shown. I thought that an Exception resolver could help me. But as far as I read the standard Exception Resolver does not suit for SpringSecurity and its scope is only Spring MVC.

```
@ControllerAdvice
```

public class ExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver{

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse responce, Object handler, Exception exception) {

    ModelAndView toReturn = new ModelAndView();
    toReturn.setView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
    toReturn.addObject("message", exception.getMessage());
    toReturn.addObject("exceptionClass", exception.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    HttpStatus exceptionStatus = getStatus(exception);
    responce.setStatus(exceptionStatus.value());        
    return toReturn;
}

private HttpStatus getStatus(Exception exception){

    if (exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException)
        return HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;        
    return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
}   
}
```

Is there any way to resolve the exception of `UserDetailsService`?

**UPDATE**

```
15:42:37,948 DEBUG qtp1052330967-15 security.DelegateRequestMatchingFilter:137 - preAuthenticatedPrincipal = dhdg, trying to authenticate
15:42:37,950  INFO qtp1052330967-15 security.CustomUserDetailsService:57 - looking for authorities for sm header value: [dhdg]
15:42:37,989 DEBUG qtp1052330967-15 security.DelegateRequestMatchingFilter:225 - Cleared security context due to exception
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: there is no opened sessions with this sm user header value
    at de.escosautomation.restserver.security.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.loadUserDetails(UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:113)
    at de.escosautomation.restserver.security.DelegateRequestMatchingFilter.doFilter(DelegateRequestMatchingFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of that 500 error?

Comment: @holmis83 500 code is shown in http representation of the error. The Java trace looks like a normal exception.

Answer (score 4):

I think I see what is going wrong here. Since you use `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`, a `UsernameNotFoundException` is not really handled. This because in a typical pre-authenticated environment, it is already verified that the user exists.

Instead you should return a `UserDetails` object with state *disabled* or *locked*.

If you can't read the user information at all, you could throw a `AuthenticationServiceException`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is related to Spring Security configuration, Commonly when we want to change the Http Error code we do that by implementing our own 
 authentication-failure-handler and authentication-success-handler as required and then pointing those beans something like bellow:

```
 <form-login
     authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
     authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler"
  />

 <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler"
   class="org.rest.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
   <beans:bean id="myFailureHandler" class=
  "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
```

For your other doubt

"I thought that an Exception resolver could help me. But as far as I read the standard Exception Resolver does not suit for SpringSecurity and its scope is only Spring MVC"

We should throw exception in our custom UserDetailsService implementation to break the authentication chain and let the Spring Security know that the credentials(say example) provided by user does not match.

do let me know if I missed something to explain. I hope This will help and yes

Happy Codings!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Actually I have a realization of SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler but it does not work: even the log lines are not printed out.